# Tense mismatch when stating a scientific fact

Tags: tense, verbs

> The machine **generated** an electric field where the N particles
> **have** an affinity for the M particles.

Can you use have instead of had when you're stating a scientific fact? I couldn't come up with a scientific fact in this example, so that's the best I could do, but let's assume the above is a true scientific fact. Is this grammatical or not?

Comment: I would say this is not grammatical, at least in a scientific paper, but in casual speech it would probably go by without comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facts are usually expressed with the present tense:

> A body in free-fall *accelerates* at 9.8 m/s²

But when you describe a particular experiment you would use the past tense:

> The stone was dropped and *accelerated* at 9.8 m/s².

So you should decide if you are describing a general fact about the machine

> The machine generates a field in which N particles have an affinity for M particles.

Or a particular run of the machine which occurred in the past:

> The machine generated a field in which the N particles had an affinity for the M particles.

There is no rule against mixing tenses if you are talking about different times.

> The baker *made* a cake which *has* pink icing and *is* in my cupboard now; we *will eat* it tomorrow.
>
> Pythagoras *wrote* a theorem that the square of the hypotenuse of a right-triangle *equals* the sum of the squares of the shorter sides.

Answer (score 0):

Facts are often stated in present tense just like news, for example: "Breaking News, Blue team defeats Red team by one goal".
And when you get to it, you find out that the event took place hours ago.

I have seen such mix-ups, but I know there was a grammar for it. I had some friends who studied English translation and they told me that. I guess the text is wrong: either it is not the whole or it's just wrong.

Comment: This is an answer.  If you want to comment to clarify a question you can do so. But this is not a comment. It is an attempt to answer.

Comment: @JamesK thank for... but i do not have the reputation to leave a comment would you PLEASE tell me how can I do it ????
I know its an answer I can read brother, but what can I do just look at my badge and see the number its 24 and I still have 26 reputation points to go for commenting... Please tell me what should I do ???

Comment: @JamesK thanks for editing though :)

Comment: You get to comment at 50 reputation.  Just write a  couple of good answers or a couple of good questions.  But don't use comments a space to write weak answers.  Comments should be used to ask for clarification and to suggest improvements: not to write half answers.

Comment: @JamesK yeah You are right... but I have seen people answer in comments when they are not sure about their answers and i was not sure so I marked it as comment not an actual answer

Comment: That's right.  But don't copy them!